# How exactly the Hooks will works

Tags: hook

I searched some results so far but still didn't get an idea on hooks concept,how the hooks will work and in which cases the hooks will help us
can anyone explain me with **simple code** and suggest with good links thanks in advance.

Comment: Wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,i want to know the simplistic code in hooks with call back funtions.